# How to create and manage Matrix of buttons in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, matrix

I have a matrix of bits 20x23.
I need to represent this matrix in a winform (GUI).
The idea is that the user will be able to change the content of specific cell by clicking the relevant button, that represent the specific cell in the matrix.
(When the user click a button, the relevant bit cell in the matrix is being inverted)

I have considered using `GRID` for this, but due to GUI (Design) issue, it is not possible to use it.

How can I create and manage 20x23 (=460) buttons effectively and keep it correlated to the real matrix ?

Comment: Using a `DataGridView` sounds like the best option. Please tell us why you decided against using it.

Comment: Because I need to add some paintings between the bits: in every row, the first 3 bits are address bits, the next 2 bits are operating mode, the next 16 bits are data bits... etc... I'd like to split it into groups visually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that difficult, I would start with a method that will generate a button matrix for you. This matrix consists of Buttons, where the ID (ie. Tag) will correspond to the correct cellNumber (you might consider passing the coordinates as a Point instance as well, I will leave that up for you to decide).

So basically, it comes to this, where all the buttons are rendered on a panel (`panel1`):

```
...

#region Fields
//Dimensions for the matrix
private const int yDim = 20;
private const int xDim = 23;
#endregion

...

private void GenerateButtonMatrix()
{

  Button[,] buttonMatrix = new Button[yDim, xDim];

  InitializeMatrix(ref matrix);  //Corresponds to the real matrix
  int celNr = 1;

  for (int y = 0; y < yDim; y++)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < xDim; x++)
    {
      buttonMatrix[y,x] = new Button()
        {
          Width = Height = 20,
          Text = matrix[y, x].ToString(),
          Location = new Point( y * 20 + 10, 
                                x * 20 + 10),  // <-- You might want to tweak this
          Parent = panel1,
        };
      buttonMatrix[y, x].Tag = celNr++;
      buttonMatrix[y,x].Click += MatrixButtonClick;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, all 460 buttons have a custom EventHandler connected to the ClickEvent, called `MatrixButtonClick()`. This eventhandler will handle the ClickEvent and may determine on which button the user has clicked. By retrieving the tag again, you may calculate the correct coordinate which corresponds to the 'real' matrix.

```
private void MatrixButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (sender is Button)
  {
    Button b = sender as Button;
    //The tag contains the cellNr representing the cell in the real matrix
    //To calculate the correct Y and X coordinate, use a division and modulo operation
    //I'll leave that up to you :-)
    .... Invert the real matrix cell value
  }
}
```

I will not give away everything, since it is a nice practice for you to achieve :).

Answer (score 0):

I would:
1) create an object with needed properties
2) fill a list and fill with values
3) iterate list creating buttons and assigning its click handler and button's name (for name something like button_rowindex_colindex)
4) inside click handler, assign value to object cell by detecting which button was clicked